# Images loss every time on server when run "docker-compose up --build" + Django

Tags: django, image, docker-compose

I had a setup docker on Django project, images are stored on server but whenever I upload changes on server and then run **"docker-compose up --build"** then it loss every images that I uploaded, path showing images there but I am not able to view it. I don't know want happened there. if anyone have idea what to do for that ? How to resolved this issue ? is there any things need to add in docker-compose file ?

Below is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  web-django:
  web-static:

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    build: .
    image: project_web
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  celery:
    image: project_web
    command: celery -A project_name worker -l info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
  celery-beat:
    image: citc_web
    command: celery -A project_name beat -l info
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
```

I want solution of it, what i missing on above file and want to resolve it.

Comment: Are you running it with `DEBUG=True` or `DEBUG=False`?

Comment: @Tarquinius , with DEBUG=True